# How can I mount JFS (not zfs) on Nexenta (or Solaris)?

Tags: solaris, nexenta, jfs

How can I mount a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFS_(file_system)'>JFS (not ZFS) filesystem on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexenta'>Nexenta (or Solaris)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSolaris doesn't support JFS (either of the file systems called JFS).